# modification affect all dataframe in lieu of column selected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I use this code to apply modification on the first 200 column only of a dataframe (total of 2000).
The row and column selected are ok, modification work grate, but when it is "paste" back in the dataframe, all 2000 column are affected

this is my code:

```
df.iloc[:, 0:200] = scaler.transform(df.iloc[:, 0:200])
```

Comment: It work fine on my test environment

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but I re install my environnement due to an other problem and now it work...